# Rubik font not rendering anymore

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, google-fonts

I have got a website running with the Google Fonts Rubik for ages. This morning it appears that this font is not rendering anymore on my desktop (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) and several  others, coming up fine on my Smartphone. I switched to Roboto for the time being.

Any idea ?

This http://www.mejoresdatos.cl/FontIssue.aspx shows what shown below:

[image: Samples showing the issue]

Comment: It doesn't appear on Google's site either: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rubik?authuser=0&subset=hebrew

Comment: I didn't think about looking into it.  I just sent a feedback to Google Fonts.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue, although the font still appears correctly on Windows 10 machines.  It is not visible on Windows 7.

Comment: Since a few hours this seems to work again. Google seems to have fixed the font...

Comment: Yes, the font is being rendered again. Don't know why and how it happened though.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here it only happens on Windows 7 Machines no matter the browser. OSX and all mobile devices I have tested on it is working on.

Answer (score 0):

https://fonts.google.com/?query=Rubik. See this is not even working here. Temporarily you can try embedding the font through CSS. Till google solves this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what worked for me was simply to force a new fetch rather than rely on the cache.

i.e. I added the parameter &cache=clear to the font.googleapis.com URL:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:400,500,700,900&cache=clear';
```